# Python re.findall hangs on certain websites

Tags: python, regex, python-requests

I´ve got a python script to loop through a list of websites/domains to **scrape** phones and e-mails from my clients websites, 99% of websites **scrapes** are OK and works. Some websites just hangs and cant even force break operation, like it is on an insane loop. Below an example. Anyone could help me improve or fix this?

```
import requests,re

try:   
    r = requests.Session()
    f = r.get('http://www.poffoconsultoria.com.br', verify=False, allow_redirects=False,timeout=(5,5) )
    s = f.text                  
    tels = set(re.findall(r"\s?\(?0?[1-9][1-9]\)?[-\.\s][2-5]\d{3}\.?-?\s?\d{4}",s))
    emails = set(re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",s))
    print(tels)
    print(emails)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Funny thing is, this happens when website has instant pop-up windows on home page. using Python 2.7.16 | requests==2.21.0

Comment: What is the `text`  value then?

Comment: @RicardoFrasson Is it findall that he says is hanging or the requests library?

Comment: It is not hanging, just taking a long time.

Comment: Remove `\s?` and it will already speed up matching. All the optional patterns at the start are making it real slow.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is the second regular expresion which is slow. The first one is much faster (about 5  seconds in my computer).

Comment: The second one is fine, it can't be slow.

Comment: Having the first regular expression in the example is just distracting, as well as the useless try ... except.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well it is in my computer. How long did it take you to run it?

Comment: Dude. It's likely the length of the page. That thing is tremendous and contains JavaScript. I answered below.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "Your expression took too long to finish and was terminated. Please increase the timeout and try again." with the timeout set to the maximum available 100 seconds. Do you get something different?

Comment: Ok, I see where the issue is.

Comment: Use `r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b'`

Comment: @FailSafe Its the re.findall r

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Cannot remove `\s?` at the beggining it wont get this http://feirasites.com.br/ sites phone number. Its pretty fast here, I just dont want it to hang forever.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/j2Gw2O/1, `\s?` is totally redundant as it matches an optional whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `\s?` from the first regex (you do not really need a whitespace at the start of the match), or replace with `(?<!\S)` if you want to only match after a whitespace or start of string.

The real problem is with the second regex where `.` resides in a character class that is quantified with `+`. The `\.` that follows it also matches a `.` and that makes it a problem when no matching text appears in the string. This is [**catastrophic backtracking**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Since the matches you expect are whole words, I suggest enhancing the pattern by 1) adding word boundaries, 2) making all adjoining subpatterns match different types of chars.

Use

```
r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b'
```

to match emails.

See the `(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+` part: it matches one or more repetitions of 1 or more alphanumeric/hyphen chars followed with a dot, and there is no `\.` after this pattern, there is an alpha character class, so there should be no problem like the one present before.

Comment: Quoted: "The real problem is with the second regex where `.` resides in a character class that is quantified with  +. The \. that follows it also matches a . and that makes it a problem when no matching text appears in the string." `....` So true. Nice catch.

Comment: I add to that that `[A-Za-z0-9_%+-]+` appear, but the wordbounds idea considering he's looking for e-mails was excellent.

Comment: @FailSafe The problem with the pattern is the 2 adjoining subpatterns that may match the same text and the preceding one is quantified with a quantifier of unknown/non-fixed length. The word boundaries are there to make matching more stable by the regex engine, Python regex is not quite good at matching unanchored patterns, it is always a good idea to find some more specific boundary at the start. Here, a word boundary seems a valid approach.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks it worked. Changed the e-mail regex to `r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b'` and it passed tru without hanging. I just copied and pasted the regex e-mail pattern  from some place else on the internet and didnt even check. I edited only the phone patter regex to match my country area code and numbers. Didnt even noticed the e-mail pattern was bad formated. Its so much faster now as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

So. I got the website data fine in Python27 using `>>> string = requests.get('http://www.poffoconsultoria.com.br').text`

I then took the length of the string and it was `>>> len(strings)
474038` That's a really high value.

So for problems like these when one sees regex take such a long time (really, after getting the length of the page), you should visit the page in your browser and `inspect the page source`

When I inspected the page in my browser I found these:

[image]

[image]

The second regex `[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+` will definitely hang (really, take a long time) because it isn't quantifiable and has to search through those ginormous portions.

You either need to chunk the page or limit your regex. Or you could write a function that discards dictionary data if you suspect that what you need to return won't appear inside of them; basically though, those huge dictionaries above are causing the regex you posted to take a long time.

Comment: So, what do you suggest as a solution? Looks like a suggestion and not an answer. OP knows already the string is large. Chunking the string is not an option as it might cut the text in the middle of an expected match. How do you suggest to limit the regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yea. My last sentence is to chunk it or potentially provide limitations on the regex. But really I don't think those are efficient solutions. I mainly wanted to have the ability to post screenshots because of the conversation above but had no intent to get a +1. I was hoping someone would piggy-back off of this to provide the best possible answer because my suggestion would literally be "write a function that splits the pages into chunks and returns found items through recurring iterations on the split up strings"

Answer (score 0):

Use valid email

```
(?i)(?:("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"@)|((?:[0-9a-z](?:\.(?!\.)|[-!#$%&'*+/=?^`{}|~\w])*)?[0-9a-z]@))(?:(\[(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|((?:[0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))
```

Comment: [This is not a good idea](https://regex101.com/r/gpPFQ9/1), it still brings the timeout issue.